# Zoom on current location Google Maps Android API

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a map which can show my current location

[image]

I'm trying to make the make the map zoom in automatically to the current location as soon as I open it. This is the code I'm using:

```
 Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
    if (location != null)
    {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
```

This code is supposed to the make the map zoom on my current location; but this is where the map is zooming in instead

[image]

On the following picture, the black circle is where the map is zooming on when it launches, and you can also actually see my current location too.

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between your location and location shown by the map ?

Comment: it shows the lastKnow locaiton data from the GPS...`getLastKnownLocation`..

Comment: @tahsinRupam i edited the post

Comment: Check this, [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)  It may help you